# Delay the installation/configuration of my Debian package

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb, packaging

I'm working on a custom Debian package and I'd like to delay its installation/configuration when installed with other packages, eg;

```
$ sudo apt-get install htop curl my-pkg rsync ...
```

Apt-get should install all other packages and let my-pkg to the end, any ideas to accomplish this within the maintainer scripts?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not going to work. Apt orders packages depending on their relations. If they are not related, apt will apply each step on all packages then continue to next step.